# Twitter signup issue android sdk

Tags: android, twitter, twitterkit, twitter-login

I'm using https://github.com/twitter-archive/twitter-kit-android for authentication by twitter in android, but I have an issue when the Twitter android app is not installed on the device, and pressing ***signup*** instead of login, this message appears:

[image]

So any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of Android is this? What browser engine is the web view using? The reason that the code is in “twitter-archive” on GitHub is that it is no longer supported.

Comment: different android systems 9 and 11 and different devices, Do you have any suggestions for another Twitter kit?